# Runtime variable creation Python 3.1.2

Tags: python

How would i go about making a function to create a certain number of uniquely named variables at runtime, based on initial user input? For instance, user enters dimensions 400 x 400, (x and y), so i would want the function to create 1600 (400 * 400) variables, each to represent every different point on a grid 400 by 400.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is an array, a list or a tuple of 400*400 points.

So create a class that stores the information you want at each point, and then create a list of size 400*400 of those class objects.

You can do it this way:

```
width = 400
height = 400
m = [[0]*width for i in range(height)]
```

And then access points in your field like so:

```
m[123][105] = 7
```

To set point (123,105) to 7.

If you want to store more than just a number at each point, create a class like I suggested:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

And then create your list of "MyClass" objects like so:

```
m = [[MyClass(0,0,0) for i in range(400)] for j in range(400)]
```

Comment: Sweet. Thank you, i should be able to implement that into my code.

Comment: An array is not a tuple nor is it a list. A tuple is immutable and has fixed length. A list is mutable but has a dynamic length. An array is mutable and (usually) has a static length. (The latter is due to the underlying structure of one big solid block making insertions and deletions a rather costly affair).

Comment: 400x400 would take a trifling (by today's standards) meg or two. For storing something larger I'd use a list of `array`-s from same-named module, and for things that are seriously larger, `numpy`. It seems that simple integers are stored anyway, not arbitrary objects. E.g. `initializer = [0]*width; matrix = [array('i', initializer) for x in range(height)]`

Comment: `[MyClass(0,0,0)]*400` creates 400 references to the same object.  You'll need `[[MyClass(0,0,0) for i in range(400)] for j in range(400)]`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, you're right. I guess my Python is rustier than I thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to create a different variable for each point on the grid? If there are lots of points with default value of say 0, don't create an array with a bunch of 0s.  Instead, create an empty dictionary `D = {}`. Store data as `D[(x,y)] = anything`.  Access your data by `D.get((x,y), 0)`. Where `D.get(key, default value)` This saves memory.

Btw, 400*400 is not 1600.  Rather 160,000